# How does CSRF Token work for a sign up request

Tags: django, csrf

I am just getting to learn Django, and CSRF Token seems to be an important aspect in terms of preventing cross-site request forgery.

However, I am a little bit confused about its role in a sign up function. From my understanding, the CSRF Token is sent from the backend server to the frontend server after the user sends an initial request from the frontend server. Then in proceeding request to the backend server, the backend server checks if there is a valid CSRF token from the frontend and send a response accordingly. *However, if a user is signing up or logging in for the first time, without any cookies on the browser whatsoever, **is it possible (or necessary) to check for CSRF token in a Django signup/signin view function?***

If it is necessary, what is the mechanism, assuming separate backend and frontend server, behind validating CSRF token in such scenario?

Comment: It sets the cookie. It does not require a user to be attached, cookies are session-oriented, not user-oriented.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is almost correct. The CSRF-token validates that you made a request to the page first, and thus got a certain token. This token can be send as a cookie, but you can also work with a hidden form element. The browser typically ensures that a script served by a certain host, can only retrieve cookies provided by the same host. So if a script served by a different host would try to make a request to your website, it can not access the cookies, and therefore thus can not work with such cookie.

If we would work with the scenario of the cookie, then you don't need to log in or sign up to get cookies. Indeed, cookies are small fragments of data that are send in a response header. So if your browser makes a (GET) request to visit the signup page, then Django will already send a CSRF-token as cookie.

But moreover you don't need to use the cookie anyway. A typical use-case is to work with the [**`{% csrf_token %}`** template tag <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#csrf-token). This template tag produces a *hidden* form element with the name `csrfmiddlewaretoken` to the generated CSRF token. If you then submit the form, it will also submit the CSRF-token as part of the form data.

Comment: From my understanding of the Django documentation, it seems that Django's csrf protection mechanism generates a random csrf token for every request (I also see that by logging get_token(request) method multiple times in the same API call)? I see how it is okay with the {% csrf_token %} template tag. However, if I want to use an external client server instead (say React), AND if I want to test APIs with Postman, how could I ever send the right csrf token given that it is randomized? Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelMo: you can retrieve the cookie that Django serves in the response that thus loads the (react) template. For an external client server, that is of course a problem. In that case, one typically makes a (REST) API without csrf protection.